# @PostConstruct and autowiring a MessageChannel

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I'm having a problem with Spring Cloud Stream. The thing is that I have a bean that will write to Kafka as soon as it's created (method annotated with @PostConstruct), so I autowire the appropriate MessageChannel and set the destination and binder properties in application.yml. It goes like this:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Sender
{
    private final MessageChannel output;

    @PostConstruct
    public void start()
    {
       output.send(new GenericMessage("Hello world");  
    }
}
```

And application.yml

```
spring:
    cloud:
        stream:
            bindings:
              output:
                destination: someData
                binder: kafka
```

I also have the following dependencies:

```
- spring-cloud-stream-reactive
- reactor-core
- spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka
```

The project itself is starting, but I'm getting the following exception when trying to write to the `output` in `start()` method:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers
```

Is it because Kafka binder didn't manage to bind the channel yet or what? If so, what is the alternative way to this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that from the `@PostConstruct`. It's too early. Other components might be initialized yet.

You have to move your sending logic to the `SmartLifecycle.start()` implementation.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Will try with SmartLifecycle.start() then. Thanks!