# CommandLineRunner VS SmartLifecycle

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

with `@PostConstruct` and autowiring a `MessageChannel` problem, I found a solution [SmartLifecycle.start()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44268331/postconstruct-and-autowiring-a-messagechannel)

can one also use `CommandLineRunner`?

what is the best way to start work with `MessageChannel rabbitMQ` after a full initialization of the context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot's `CommandLineRunner` (or `ApplicationRunner`) is fine.

`SmartLifecycle` is available for any Spring application, not just Boot applications.